Hide indicators for QComboBox (qdarkstyle)
I am using qdarkstyle on my PyQt5 GUI, and I am trying to make a widget with internal combo boxes. The items in the combo box all have a square indicator to the left hand side that I want to hide.
I have tried setting the style sheet with no success
class Panel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
       self.cb = QComboBox()
       self.cb.addItems(["hello", "world"])
       self.cb.setStyleSheet(self.getcbstylesheet())
       self.layout.addWidget(self.cb)
       self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def getcbstylesheet(self):
       return """
          QComboBox::indicator {
              background-color: transparent;
              selection-background-color: transparent;
              color: transparent;
              selection-color: transparent;
          }
       """


first insert the QComboBox to the layout and then set the qtstylesheet

Move self.cb.setStyleSheet(self.getcbstylesheet()) after self.setLayout(self.layout)

@eyllanesc that didn’t change anything

I was able to figure it out- it is solved with a QStyledItemDelegate, not a style sheet. First define the new delegate:
(Edited based on musicamante‘s reply)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QStyledItemDelegate, QStyleOptionViewItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex

class NoIconItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QModelIndex):
        option.decorationPosition = QStyleOptionViewItem.Position.Right
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)

Then we can use this delegate for the combo box
self.cb.setItemDelegate(NoIconItemDelegate(self.cb.view()))


The correct place to do that is not in paint(), but in initStyleOption(), right after calling the base implementation. Also, it's usually good practice to create delegates with a proper parent (usually, the view they eventually use, which in this case is the combo box view()).
